# MS SoapClient and WSDLReader error ’80020009′

Tags: asp-classic, payment-gateway, payment, soap-client

I want to create a gateway for payment and using asp classic but i got this error:

```
WSDLReader error '80020009'

WSDLReader:XML Parser failed at linenumber 0, lineposition 0, reason is: A connection with the server could not be established HRESULT=0x1: Incorrect function. - WSDLReader:Loading of the WSDL file failed HRESULT=0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect. - Client:One of the parameters supplied is invalid. HRESULT=0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect.

/fa/Payment.asp, line 23
```

here is my code:

```
<%
 If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" Then
SET objSoapClient = Server.CreateObject("MSSOAP.SoapClient30")
objSoapClient.ClientProperty("ServerHTTPRequest") = True
Call objSoapClient.mssoapinit("https://pgws.bpm.bankmellat.ir/pgwchannel/services/pgw?wsdl","PaymentGatewayImplService")
referenceid = objSoapClient.bpPayRequest ("XXXXXXX","XXXXXX","XXXXXXXX","XXX","XXXX","XXXX","XXXXX","","http://www.next.co.ir/fa/PaymentResult.asp","10")
Response.Redirect( "https://bpm.shaparak.ir/pgwchannel/startpay.mellat?RefId="&referenceid)   
End If
%>
```

is it related to SSL or something else?